# Where can I see the log of the activation and the deactivation of Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, logging

Google Chrome extensions can be activated or deactivated via `chrome://extensions/`:

Activated:

[image]

Deactivated:

[image]

Where can I see the log of the activation and the deactivation of Google Chrome extensions?

E.g.:

```
2020-09-20 23:10:01: Extension x activated.
2020-09-20 23:11:55: Extension y activated.
2020-09-20 23:15:26: Extension z deactivated.
2020-09-20 23:16:19: Extension x deactivated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting answer from [s_i_m_s](https://www.reddit.com/user/s_i_m_s) on https://redd.it/iwuh3k:

> AFAIK chrome doesn't keep a log of that but you can install an extension like [NooBoss](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nooboss/aajodjghehmlpahhboidcpfjcncmcklf) that can. I'm sure there's others that can too but that's the only extension i'm aware of off hand.

NooBoss does indeed work well. https://ainoob.com/en/project/nooboss:

> Want to track the history of your apps/extensions? Go to History page! Here you can see when did apps/extensions got enabled, disabled, installed, removed, and their version! So you can tell when did they update the extension, or since which version did the extension stop working.

[image]